# Heroku performing collectstatic as expected on deployment?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have Django setup to collect my static files and copy them into S3 using django-storages and this works like a charm when I explicitly run

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

However, I expect Heroku to perform this action automatically upon deployment (i.e. git push to Heroku) as described in this documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets . Apparently, the output of:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput
```

determines whether or not collectstatic is configured correctly (collectstatic works correctly when I run it explicitly). I get:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput
Running `python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput` attached to terminal... up, run.9607
Pretending to copy '/app/app_pkg/static/robots.txt'
.... # Lot of similar outputs not shown
16 static files copied.
```

That looks *good* to me but the documentation does not specify what I should see. When I deploy the project, everything appears to work fine and complete successfully.

```
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
       Cleaning up...
-----> Collecting static files
       16 static files copied.

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
```

The files do not show up in my S3 bucket though. If I then explicitly run

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

all the files show up in the S3 bucket. I think Heroku should be performing this action for me and I'm not sure why its not. Is this expected behavior? Should I need to do it myself?

Comment: Some more info on a [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417322/django-collectstatic-from-heroku-pushes-to-s3-everytime). I haven't found a solution either.

Comment: $ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Odd no one has answered you yet!  Simply add this to the beginning of your Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

This will run python manage collectstatic every time your app is deployed on Heroku.

The cleanest way is to chain it to your existing Procfile like so:

```
web: python my_django_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; bin/gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_app/settings.py
```

Credit goes to Matthew Phiong & [his awesome blog post](http://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku)

Comment: Modifying the Procfile did work well and still does. Thanks. I now use the [user-env-compile lab](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#config-vars-during-build) Heroku built (mentioned by Kenneth) to support including environment variables in the build (which django-storages requires) so that static asset collection is performed by Heroku without the Procfile needing to be modified.

Comment: Don't think is the best answer because everytime you start a new dyno this will run. look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Recommend people use release which was introduced to heroku much after the best answer was posted.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase

```
release: python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput
```