# Django on Heroku doesn't call collectstatic

Tags: python, django, heroku

Based on this articles https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Heroku supposed to call

> python manage.py collectstatic

after I configure settings with this django_heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

my config vars:

```
DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC: 1
DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC: 0
```

my buildpack: `heroku/python`

I put this code on the last line of my settings.py

```
import django_heroku

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

and my folder looks like this

```
apps
|---apps
  |---settings
    |---base.py
    |---settings.py
```

This is my build log

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.7
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Found python-3.7.7, removing
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing python-3.7.6
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting asgiref==3.2.7
         Downloading asgiref-3.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0
         Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
       Collecting Django==3.0.6
         Downloading Django-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
       Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1
         Downloading django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
         Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Collecting psycopg2==2.7.5
         Downloading psycopg2-2.7.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7 MB)
       Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
         Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
       Collecting pytz==2020.1
         Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.3.1
         Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
       Collecting whitenoise==5.1.0
         Downloading whitenoise-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Installing collected packages: asgiref, dj-database-url, sqlparse, pytz, Django, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, gunicorn, psycopg2-binary
       Successfully installed Django-3.0.6 asgiref-3.2.7 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-20.0.4 psycopg2-2.7.5 psycopg2-binary-2.8.5 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1 whitenoise-5.1.0
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> release, web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 58.8M
-----> Launching...
 !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
```

I also try add run python manage.py collectstatic on procfile like this one suggested but it doesn't run [Heroku performing collectstatic as expected on deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253978/heroku-performing-collectstatic-as-expected-on-deployment?rq=1)

Try to run it manually through heroku's bash and it's fine and running well

so does anyone know why heroku doesn't call collectstatic?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the rootcause

I think it's because I have these config vars

```
DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC: 1
DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC: 0
```

which after I delete those config vars it works.